# java hotspot(tm) 64-bit server vm warning ignoring option permsize=256m support was removed in 8.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I want to run eclipse , I got the following warning :

```
java hotspot(tm) 64-bit server vm warning ignoring option permsize=256m support was removed in 8.0
```

How can I remove this message ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be already fixed issue with not supporting MaxPermSize param since Java 8. 
For more info look here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/203 
and here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/issues/67

Another option would be downgrade to Java 7.